# How to get syntax error on Ace editor and alert it

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, ace-editor

I have been trying to customise syntax error on Ace editor. I disabled live syntax checker using this code below

```
 editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
```

I have googled and try several answers on stackoverflow, no one of these work.

I want to get syntax error like

if there is error or warning

1. On click run button
2. Get editor error or warning
3. Append it in a bootstrap alert div
4. Return false (do not run the code).

Please i need help. I am ready to learn it step by step.

Answer (score 10):

I follow syntax issue created on Ace github and add some answers i got on stackoverflow.

Here his how i fix it

```
editor.getSession().on("changeAnnotation", function () {
  var annot = editor.getSession().getAnnotations();

  for (var key in annot) {
    if (annot.hasOwnProperty(key))
      console.log(annot[key].text + "on line " + " " + annot[key].row);
  }
});
```

Comment: Annotations are actually an array of objects, not an object itself. So you should iterate through them as an array, not with a `for..in`.